# cannot infer type-variable(s) while implementing a generic class

Tags: java, generics

I've defined the following class:

```
public class AttributeVisitor extends SimpleAnnotationValueVisitor8<Object, Object> {

    public AttributeVisitor() {
        super();
    }

    public AttributeVisitor(Object defaultValue) {
        super(defaultValue);
    }

    @Override
    public Object visitEnumConstant(VariableElement c, Object attribute) {
        return super.visitEnumConstant(c, attribute);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use it in the following snipped

```
for(Map.Entry<? extends ExecutableElement, ? extends AnnotationValue> mirrorValues: annotationMirror.getElementValues().entrySet()){
    mirrorValues.getValue().accept(new AttributeVisitor());
}
```

On compiling, I'm getting the following error:

```
method accept in interface javax.lang.model.element.AnnotationValue cannot be applied to given types;
[ERROR] required: javax.lang.model.element.AnnotationValueVisitor<R,P>,P
[ERROR] found: com.cvent.analytics.validator.AttributeVisitor
[ERROR] reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) R,P
[ERROR] (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Any idea, what's wrong here?

Comment: What's the type of `annotationMirror.getElementValues()`?

Comment: Its Map<? extends ExecutableElement,? extends AnnotationValue> Ref:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/AnnotationMirror.html#getElementValues--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The `accept` method expects two arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/AnnotationValue.html#accept-javax.lang.model.element.AnnotationValueVisitor-P-). This compiles:

```
mirrorValues.getValue().accept(new AttributeVisitor(), null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Error:

```
cannot infer type arguments for `Resource<>`
```

Reason:

```
cannot infer type-variable(s) T
    (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to ResponseMessage)
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class Resource
```

Solution for this :

```
new ResponseMessage("Message", null, null)) by replacing string message
```